# Create Derived Column in SSIS that resets on Change of ID

Tags: sql-server, ssis, derived

What I'm hoping to do is to create a derived column that creates an incremental value, but resets on a patient ID.

From the screenshot below, what I currently have are the columns DCACCT, DCCODE, and DCDESC.  But I want to add the derived column that contains that increments by 1 for each comment associated with a patient ID (DCACCT). But resets itself back to 1 on change of patient ID.

[image: Desired Output]

Could anyone offer any assistance on how I might accomplish this?

I currently have a derived column that increments itself for every patient ID with an "N" prefix, but I am not sure how I could modify this expression to suit my needs here.

[image: Transformation Editor]

Comment: The OOB components in the data flow do not allow inspection of rows ahead or behind the current row. To achieve what you're looking for, you'll need a script component to generate those surrogate ids, resetting whenever your sentinel value changes. There might even be a dupe of this question. Just make sure your source data is sorted before it hits the component

Comment: Even better than a script component, if the source component is a SQL query, you can create the column in the query (with ROW_NUMBER()) and not have to add any additional transformations to your data flow.

Comment: Thanks Tab, I'll check out Row_Number to see if that will take care of my needs.

Comment: did you try slowly changing dimension control

Comment: Thanks Tab, your comment pointed me in the right direction where I was able to use a Row_Number function to achieve my desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve my end goal, I imported the data from the DB2 as I had been doing, but then I created a view on the data to use the Row_Number() function within SQL Server:

`Row_Number() Over (Partition By DCACCT Order By DCACCT) [PCMT],`

My next step possibly could have been achieved with SSMS, but I created a new sequence container in SSIS and created a derived column to add my prefix and suffix:

[image: Derived Column]